# Как защитить cookie с незащищенным каналом?

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование

Всем известно, что использование алгоритма хеширования md5 уже давно не является решением всех проблем.

В задаче: отсутствует SSL, незащищенный канал, может быть запросто реализована атака Man in the Middle.

1. Как в таком случае защитить cookie?
2. Собственно, каким бы алгоритмом (алгоритмами) хеширования воспользовались бы вы при разработке web-страницы, а точнее проектировки базы данных и системы аутентификации, в таких "условиях"?
3. Что скажете о связке sha(md5(pass))?

Comment: а поясните, пожалуйста, чем md5 плоха?

Comment: Читайте md5-Коллизии, RainbowTables.
Не говоря уже о более мелких базах данных по восстановлению md5 паролей. И на wiki есть кое-что про уязвимости md5, уделите внимание Китайцам.

Comment: CHAP все проблемы решает. А если у вас такой страшный защищённый сайт, то используйте хороший протокол аутентификации. Выбор хэшфункции некритичен при правильном использовании криптографии

Comment: а коллизии в sha всего лишь в 4 млрд раз реже встречаются

Comment: Собственно я не хотел выбирать между sha и md5. Я спрашивал про их комбинацию.

И, к сожалению, CHAP не решает всех проблем, а создает новые. 

Во-первых, так как каждый раз генерируется новый challenge, сохранение нового response в cookie мне кажется затруднительным.

Во-вторых необходима в таком случае система создания md5 на стороне клиента, а так как не все жалуют JavaScript, то эта затея тоже не совсем приемлема.

Comment: нет, challenge обычно генерируется один раз, чтоб получить сессионный ключ, session_id, который и болтается в куках. Что значит "не все жалуют JavaScript"? А как вы аутентификацию без вычислений на клиенте будете делать? Пароль в открытом виде передавать? Здесь sha уже как мёртвому припарка.

Comment: Нет конечно, в открытом виде только через ssl.
Но что будет, если время сессии истекает?

Comment: вы небось без проблем работаете с hashcode.ru? :) Если нужна безопасность, то https поомжет. Если у вас интернет-банк, то высылайте код подтверждения операции на телефон клиента, а в договоре услуг банкинга предупреждайте, что всё это небезопасно. И всё норм.

Comment: Батенька, да у вас параноя :)
Используйте md5 с "солью" или даже комбинацию sha1 и md5 и будет вам  счастье, к примеру:
$salt1 = "Hello Dex"; $salt2 = "Goodbay Dex";
substr(md5($salt1.$pass.$salt2), 0, 16).substr(sha1($salt1.$pass.$salt2), 16, 16)

В данном случае пароль не найдут по rainbow. и остальных методики тут тоже безсильны

Comment: Это не параноя, а вынужденная мера. С солью или без, но те же куки можно упереть. Поэтому в моем случае приемлимым кажется только вариант yapycoder.
SSL пока использовать невозможно по техническим причинам.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вас не устраивает MD5, то вы можете попробовать SHA-256 или SHA-512 в случае, если речь идёт о какой-то параное.

Использовать SHA + MD5 не следует. Скрещивать два криптографических алгоритма вообще не рекомендуется, так как безопасность может не вырасти, а наоборот снизиться. Поэтому просто выберите себе хороший алгоритм и пользуйтесь.

А ещё вы можете попробовать зашифровать все пароли каким-нибудь ключём, спрятанным в надёжном месте.

Если же речь идёт о каком-то действительно параноидальном случае, то, как уже заметили ранее здесь, то в действительности есть куча разных схем аутентификации (например, паттерн Auth Token) и они не обязывают вас использовать именно хэш-функцию.

И вот ещё: сессии тречатся чаще всего либо через куки и иногда через IP+куки. Таким образом, от кражи куков защититься нельзя никак кроме как выдавать на каждый запрос новые куки (генерировать новый сессионный ключ)

Совсем другое дело - хранение в БД. Если вы боитесь, что кто-то украдёт саму базу.. то это совсем другая задача. Стоит разделить эти две проблемы.

**UPD**

И помните, что один из принципов криптостойкости гласит, что секретность алгоритма или каких-то начальных данных (например, соль) не гарантируют безопасность.

Comment: Нет, дело не в базе. Спасибо. Кое-что прояснили.

Answer (score 1):

Я видел статью где предлагали пользоваться следующим алгоритмом:

- берем пароль
- делаем хэш(md5)
- ломаем хэш своей функцией
- делаем хэш получившегося

своя функция предполагает замену букв в хэше по позиции в оригинальной записи определенных букв другими например:

a=@ s=$ o=0
еще можно добавить чтобы pзаменялась на заглавную букву

исходный пароль: password

хэш: 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

ломаный хэш: 5@$$c03b5@$$60d61@$$20deB@$$c099

второй хэш: 212fee4334b1eea4911bea4051a61c7d

можно также не повторять замену а заменить часть слова, как вариант начать замену от позиции = длине пароля, используйте фантазию.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый Dex, нужно было сразу задавать вопрос, как защитится от кражи кук.
Есть популярная схема для этого, посредством этого же делается автологин на сайтах:

есть таблица примерно такой структуры:

```
id  | user_id   | token1    | token2
```

когда юзер логинится на сайт (вводит логин и пароль) вы ложите в таблицу запись. token1 и token2 является каким-то хешем от случайных данных (не столь важно какой алгоритм хеширования)

в куки ложатся эти токены например в таком виде:
token1:token2 (или же, зная длину хеша можно не использовать сепаратор ":")

Так, а теперь ситуация:
Юзер1 (истинный хозяин этих кук) возвращается на сайт, мы парсим куки и видем что для token1 и token2 есть такая запись, пускаем его внутрь, **при этом!** меняем значение token2 на другой случайный хеш, как в базе так и в самих куках.

А теперь представим что злоумышленник стянул наш token1 и token2, естественно после захода на сайт token2 поменялся. 
После этого на сайт заходит Юзер1, мы видем что token1 есть у нас в базе, но token2 отличается от ожидаемого, поэтому мы:

- удаляем эту запись из таблицы токенов
- удаляем все активные сессии этого юзера с token1

таким образом куки у злоумышленника становятся не действительными.
Но при этом Юзер1 должен заново вводить пароль что бы попасть в систему.

Если вы скажете что можно поменять пароль, воспользовавшись куками, то для этой системы нужно предусмотреть смену пароля с подтвержденнием через email, смена почты также должна быть с подтверждением.

Comment: Интересная идея, но я не совсем понял принцип, можно ссылку на статью или вроде того?

Comment: К моему стыду я не знаю имя этого метода :( Или хоть какое-то ключевое слово, которое позволит нагуглить статью по этому поводу.

Что именно вам не понятно ? Постараюсь разъяснить

Comment: Во-первых, я про смену пароля не говорил, достаточно будет просто сделать (в отсутствие Юзера) какую-то гадость с его аккаунтом (например, если бы это был банковский аккаунт, то перевести деньги и всё, утопическая ситуация для примера); Во-вторых, если на пользователя будут постоянно совершаться подобные атаки, работать он не сможет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно применить такой метод. Отказываемся от куков вообще, но в каждом запросе передаём токен безопасности: `hash(<пароль>+<URL страницы>+<текущая дата-время с точностью до минуты>)`. Например, `http://example.com/some/page?security=12345678`. Понятно, что сервер может проверить корректность токена, так как он знает пароль. А злоумышленник не может сочинить этот токен, так как он не знает пароля, а перехватив HTTP-запрос, он узнает токен только для одной страницы, действующий в течение минуты.

Конечно, мы не хотим заставлять пользователя вычислять и вбивать хеш в адресную строку. Мы можем сделать либо абсолютно динамический сайт на Javascript, который в начале сеанса спрашивает пароль, а затем все страницы грузит аяксом, скрытно добавляя токены к URL'ам. Или можно хранить пароль в локальном хранилище браузера (LocalStorage), а к каждой странице добавлять Javascript, правящий все ссылки после загрузки - тогда мы можем сделать менее динамический сайт с реальными перезагрузками страниц.

Понятно, что это всё треш, но, я так понимаю, у вас проблема с неким локальным сайтом, например, сайт предприятия. В таком случае превращение сайта в такое веб-приложение, наверно, можно оправдать. Если же сайт публичный, то эти извращения не останутся незамеченными, и пользователи вас за них не полюбят.

Приведённая схема вполне безопасна, но только если man-in-the-middle у нас read-only. А вот если он может править информацию, передаваемую от сервера к клиенту, то всё плохо - он просто подменит начальную страницу своей, которая не будет хранить пароль локально, а отправит прямиком ему. И с этим ничего нельзя сделать, кроме того, что уже сделано в SSL, а именно - идентификация сервера с помощью сертификата. Ну никак нельзя узнать, "правильный" ли сервер, "правильная" ли страница авторизации ("правильная" ли соль, присланная сервером, и т.д.), не договорившись с ним о каком-нибудь общем секрете, который можно проверить, не открывая этого секрета, или не договорившись с кем-либо сторонним, кто договорился с сервером. Секрет, который можно проверить, не открывая его, означает использование криптографии с открытым ключом. Договор с кем-то сторонним - это использование стороннего сервера сертификации, сертификат которого предустановлен в клиентской системе. Эти две вещи, по большому счёту, и составляют протокол SSL, так что лучшее, что вы можете сделать - таки преодолеть вашу некую проблему, мешающую использовать SSL.

Answer (score -1):

Лучше так md5(pass.$соль)
Соль, любое значение, не случайное.

Comment: Ну и чем это лучше? В моем варианте свиснуть куки, и выдать их за свои проще простого. Читайте комментарии под вопросом.

Comment: Свисните мои куки.  Их не так просто то и свистнуть. Просто от xss получше защити и делай выводы из бд и файлов (где информация хранится ) через htmlcpecialchars();

Comment: Все зависит от проекта, в фейсбуке вообще здорово сделали для некоторых стран, при входе тебя спрашивают, покажи всех своих друзей из 10 представленых, не угадал пошел на....

Comment: А речь про XSS и не шла. Дело в том, что сеть, в которой я обитаю, далеко не идеальна и можно утащить у народа все, что не зашифровано.

Answer (score -1):

> Всем известно, что использование алгоритма хеширования md5 уже давно не является решением всех проблем.

1. Кому Всем? Многие не представляют как работает MD5!
2. Решением всех проблем является только смерть!

> Каким бы алгоритмом (алгоритмами) хеширования воспользовались бы Вы при разработке web-страницы.

При разработке Web-страницы я бы воспользовался IDE.

> а точнее проектировки базы данных и системы аутентификации?

Хранить пароль пользователя в базе данных можно в виде MD5 или использовать специальные функции языка (в PHP можно юзать hash_hmac для целей шифрования пароля с вашим любимым алгоритмом и солью)

P.S. Вы очень некорректно поставили вопрос. Я бы его скорректировал на вашем месте.

P.P.S. Так и не понял в чем у Вас проблема MD5 с солью (более 8 символов например подбирают достаточно долго - для средне статистического сервиса).

Comment: Вы, видимо, разбираетесь, как работает MD5.
Тогда поясните, как MD5 даже с солью, помещенное в cookie можно защитить от перехвата пакетов в общедоступной Wi-Fi сети, или в сети, постороенной на неуправляемых свитчах? Но при этом учтите, что SSL недоступен, а канал не шифрован

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в том как работает MD5. Защитить MD5 можно сменой соли в зависимости от времени (время жизни сессии ограничить в 5 минут). Отказаться от неуправляемых свичей. Начать использовать SSL. Вы какие-то утопичные условия ставите...

Comment: время жизни сессии ограничить в 5 минут=убить все желание посещать ваш ресурс, отказаться от неуправляемых свичей=потратить деньги на управляемые свичи либо потратить деньги на другого провайдера, использовать SSL=потратить деньги на валидный сертификат, загрузить сервер обработкой SSL. Защитить MD5 можно сменой соли=сделать фигню т.к. куки все равно могут украсть. Судя по вашему комментарию вы не разбираетесь не только в MD5 но и в компьютерной безопасности ничего не понимаете.

Comment: @Сергей, в точку!
@vit1251, Есть у меня замечательная программулина от банка, в которой логин и пароль не сохраняется, я ей поэтому и не пользуюсь. Кроме этого банковский фронт-энд есть и в интернете, логин+пароль (которые хранятся в Опере) + Challenge-Response, который я получаю с помощью чипованой карты и устройства + SSL - делают свое дело. В моем же случае Логина+Пароль не достаточно, так как нету SSL (и не важно по каким причинам), а выдать кажому карту с устройством я тоже не могу, вот и спросил, как бы вы решали подобную проблему. Не передавая ни пароль ни хеш по сети.

Comment: @Dex вы пошли по пути по которому пошли создатели 3DES. Текст вашего сообщения составлен крайне нехорошо. Ваш итоговый вопрос звучит так: "Как не передавая: пароль, хеш по сети произвести авторизацию пользователя на сайте." Скорректируйте вопрос!!!

Comment: @vit1251, я только добавлю кое-что в вопрос, ибо изначально я хотел лишь узнать, чему каждый отдает предпочтение основываясь на конкретных условиях, но в силу того, что не очень продумал вопрос, и сразу не дал толкового объяснения проблемы, дискуссия пошла по не верному пути, хорошее замечание, спасибо.